# Fix gopro hero 5 no internet after pairing

Tags: gopro

The gopro hero 5 pairing with the capture app uses the phone Wifi adapter and the phone has "no internet available" after pairing. Am I missing something? How can I use internet on the phone after pairing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect from the Gopro. While the Gopro is the hotspot and the phone connects to it, it has no way of getting out to the internet. The phone will only be connected to the internet once you disconnect it from the Gopro.

This will apply to any camera with wifi, when you are using the camera as the hotspot. Some cameras allow you to connect via 'infrastructure mode', where they connect to an existing wifi network and communicate with the phone via that network as long as the phone is also connected to the same network.